# Initialize Drawable image in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have two pictures I would like to rotate as a background image on an android app in a fragment.

Right now one is statically in the `.xml` as

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

I am trying to initialize the two photos in my `Fragment.java` but I am getting null pointer errors.

```
private Drawable img1 =
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getContext(),R.drawable.background);

private Drawable img2 =
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getContext(),R.drawable.background2);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions why I am getting a null error here?

Thanks!

Comment: Which line causes the `NullPointerException`? I suggest adding some logging just before that line to determine which variable is null.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it and

Comment: You should also checkout your logcat. (If you don't know how, a quick google search will show you.)

Comment: Are you sure the the file background.png (or jpg) is in the drawable/ folder?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `getActivity()` rather than `getContext()`. `getContext` was added in API 23, and I think results in a NPE if called in prior versions.

Comment: If that doesn't help, delay loading the Drawables until onCreate or another one of the life-cycle callbacks.

Comment: Loading the Drawables too soon is very likely the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

Call it in the onCreateView instead of assigning the value directly. it will resolve your issue.

```
private Drawable deleteIcon;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
deleteIcon= ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);}
```